# How to check that an integer is passed to Pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a simple code to check prod.py:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x ** y

add(4.1, 4)
```

This is the test code test_prod.py:

```
from prod import add
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, expected", [(4, 4, 256), (2, 3, 8)])
def test_prod(a, b, expected):
    assert add(a, b) == expected

@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected_exception, one, two", [(TypeError, 4, 'a'),])
def test_check(expected_exception, one, two):
    with pytest.raises(expected_exception):
        add(one, two)
```

Everything works well. But how do I check that the integer comes from prod.py ? In this code, prod.py returns a number with the float() data type. I need the test to fail. The test should end with success if prod.py will return int() .

I check the test like this:
python3 -m pytest /home/user/test/test_prod.py -v

This doesn't work either because it doesn't check the real data type coming from prod.py::

```
from prod import add
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, expected", [(4, 4, 256), (2, 3, 8)])
def test_prod(a, b, expected):
    assert add(a, b) == expected
    if type(expected) is not int:
        assert False

@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected_exception, one, two", [(TypeError, 4, 'a'),])
def test_check(expected_exception, one, two):
    with pytest.raises(expected_exception):
        add(one, two)
```

This code should NOT pass the test:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x ** y

add(4.1, 4)
```

This code should pass the test:

```
def add(x, y):
    return int(x ** y)


print(add(4, 4.1))
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain the problem well enough. I will tell you in more detail:

The user has a task to write an exponentiation program that works ONLY with integers. The user inserts his code on the site, and the code is checked.

That is, I need to check the data for a type that is unknown to me in advance.

Comment: Modules don't "return" anything, they might print to stdout and/or stderr when imported though. I can't think of any sensible way to tell whether some bytes captured on stdout came from `print("4")` or from `print(4)`. Why do you have a function called "add" which does "exponentiation" in a module called "prod" - are you intentionally being confusing here? :D

Answer (score 0):

Just take the type of the outcome and test it versus the integer class.

The assert on float I put in the code should be removed for your purpose, but I put it in to show that it passes with the right type.

```
def add(x, y):
    return x ** y

result  = add(4.1, 4)

assert type(result) is float
assert type(result) is int
```

Comment: That won't do. I left a clarifying comment to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a raise TypeError to add if the input is non-integer:

```
def add(x, y):
    
    if type(x) is not int or type(y) is not int:
        raise TypeError("Add expects integer input")
        
    return x ** y

result  = add(4.1, 4)
```

You can use a decorator to do this on a function provided by a third party (modified from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/)

```
# Defining the original function
def add(x, y):
    
    #if type(x) is not int or type(y) is not int:
    #    raise TypeError("Add expects integer input")
        
    return x ** y

# defining a decorator
def type_checking_decorator(func):
 
    # inner1 is a Wrapper function in
    # which the argument is called
     
    # inner function can access the outer local
    # functions like in this case "func"
    def inner1(x,y):
        if type(x) is not int or type(y) is not int:
            raise TypeError("Add expects integer input")
         
        # calling the actual function now
        # inside the wrapper function.
        func(x,y) 
        
    return inner1

 
# passing 'function_to_be_used' inside the
# decorator to control its behaviour
function_to_be_used = type_checking_decorator(add)
 
 
# calling the function
function_to_be_used(4, 4)
try:
    function_to_be_used(4.1, 4)
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of options. But all options check previously known data. I need to check the data that will come from the prod.py file, and I don't know what 3,4 or 3, 4.1 will be written there.

Comment: You need to see the 'add(4.1, 4)' some how?

Comment: Can you describe at a higher level what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to test simple python tasks on a website. The code is sent by the user. This code is written to a file prod.py . 
 python3 -m /home/user/test/test_prod.py
executed on the server side

If the code meets the conditions, the user receives a success message. All this has already been implemented. I can't check the code for the data type, according to the condition, the code should only work with integers. If I do as you wrote, the answer will always be FALSE.

Comment: The task looks like this: Write a function that accepts two numeric arguments as input. The first argument is raised to the power of the second argument, and an integer is returned.

Comment: Isn't that merely a small modification of your test:

```Python
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, expected", [(4, 4, 256), (2, 3, 8)])
def test_prod(a, b, expected):
    result = add(a, b) 
    assert result == expected
    assert type(result) is int
```

Comment: I updated my question, look at the very bottom.

Comment: Do you prefer to build your own solution, or are you interested in a tool that achieves probably most of what you are trying t o achieve?

Comment: Any of these options will suit me.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by wim it is difficult to solve the exact question you have. Evaluating other peoples code is however a challenge addressed by nbgrader.

Building such a solution for yourself is hard and potentially dangerous because you are executing code from strangers on your own server.

[nbgrader](https://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)